# How to initial and update specified submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have just clone one repository. In it, there are 4 submodules. I only want to update two of them.  How to do that?
The normal way

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

will fetch all the submodules is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the name of the submodule like this:

```
git submodule update --init submoduleName
```

Another option is to get into the submodule folder and pull the code from there.

Comment: Thank you, for the first option, it works and I can also use wildcard. The second I am afraid we can't since the folder(submodule) is empty when you first clone the repository.

Comment: Never tried with wildcards. but you can use `submodule foreach` to do it on all the submodules.